# Issue with mongoid and embedded documents

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

Ican't solve issue with deleting embedded documents - that is simply not happening even tough that parent and embedded document are getting found. I have searched other questions on Stackoverflow and Github issues but none of the suggestions work.

Here is the code responsible for deleting embedded doc (using latest sinatra, mongo and mongoid gems):

```
delete '/api/items/:id/notes/:note_id' do
    owner_email = session[:logged_user].email
    id = params[:id]
    item = ToDoItem.by_user(owner_email).find(id)
    if item.nil?
        halt 404, 'Item not found'
    else
        note_id = params[:note_id]
        note = item.notes.find(note_id)
        # logger.info BSON::ObjectId(note_id).to_s
        # logger.info note.to_json

        note.destroy      
        item.save!
        item.reload
        { :success => true }.to_json
    end
end
```

Here is model:

```
class ToDoItem
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

    field :sort_order,  type: Integer,  default: 1
    field :name,        type: String
    field :completed,   type: Boolean,  default: false
    field :owner_email, type: String
    field :categories,  type: Array,    default: ['general']
    field :id,          type: String
    embeds_many :notes

    def self.by_user(email)
        where(owner_email: email)
    end

    def self.by_category(category)
        where(categories: category)
    end

    def self.by_completed
        where(completed: true)
    end

    def id
        BSON::ObjectId(_id).to_s
    end
end

 class Note
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :text, type: String
  field :id,   type: String

  def id
    BSON::ObjectId(_id).to_s
   end

  embedded_in :todoitem
 end
```

Comment: Why would you add field `id` to each model?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I've migrated from MongoMapper to Mongoid. Mongomapper autmatically created id property and converted value to string while serializing model to json. Mongoid however doesn't do that and I was getting _id":{"$oid":"575e83f98b9b540003000004"} when serializing to json. I added this extra id property so I don't have to update my Javascript files.